# How to Access the current ViewContext

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing a module and I'd like to have access to the current ViewContext in visual basic.  It is passed in helpers but this is not a helper and I have no idea how to get to it from within a module.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why not pass it into the module? How did you plan to use the module?

Comment: Well, I'm going to use the module as sort of an htmlhelper that'll render a razor template.  I know, that's what helpers are for.  Just humor me on this. : )

Passing it from the view template is acceptable but I'd much rather not have to do that if I can grab what I need while in the module.  That and to be honest, I'm not sure how to grab it from the template either.

Comment: What part of the ViewContext do you intend to use? BTW, I strongly recommend against reinventing the wheel. It's been done already this year.

Comment: This is how I'm planning on using it.

rv = New RazorView(
    helper.ViewContext,
    PathToTemplate,
    Nothing,
    False,
    Nothing
)

Comment: HA!  I didn't realize that you can use Me in the view.  Kinda makes things easier.  smh...